# Chip identification possibly SPI driver

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, spi

I have a standing desk, which has a separate control board consisting of 7 buttons and 3 digit, 7-segment display. The controller is connected to the rest of the system via 8 cables.

Inside the controller there are following two chips:

First is what I believe a driver for the display.
[image: AD1650 chip]

The second one though had me scratching my head:
[image: MN99L2 chip]

This chip has 4-wire connection to the microprocessor, controls the display driver, and on top of that handles 5 of the 7 buttons (the last two buttons are connected directly, bypassing those chips)

Do you know what any of those chips are? And if possible even have a link for datasheet?

Answer (score 0):

The AD1650 is most probably some kind of clone of TM1650, which is LED Drive Controller / Keyboard Scan ASIC some info http://www.datasheetcafe.com/tm1650-datasheet-led-controller/

The chip connections match, the only difference I was able to find is, that on the AD1650 in my photo, the SCL and SDA are swapped, compared to TM1650.

The other chip will then be some dedicated ASIC/micro which provides the unknown protocol on one side and emits I2C on the other.